# Swift 3 - Initialize AudioStreamBasicDescription fields to zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, core-audio

In Objective-C you should always initialize the fields of a new audio stream basic description structure to zero, like this:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription myAudioDataFormat = {0};
```

I'm currently working in **Swift 3** and I was wondering how to initialize the fields of a new `AudioStreamBasicDescription` struct to zero?

```
var asbd = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
asbd.mSampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE
asbd.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
asbd.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsBigEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked
asbd.mBitsPerChannel = 16
asbd.mChannelsPerFrame = 1
asbd.mFramesPerPacket = 1
asbd.mBytesPerFrame = 2
asbd.mBytesPerPacket = 2
```

Will my first line initialize the initial fields to zero? Otherwise how is attainable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Will my first line initialize the initial fields to zero?***

YES.

As you know, Swift generates a default initializer taking all fields as parameters for Swift-defined structs which has no explicit initializer definitions.

And when importing C-structs, Swift generates another initializer taking `()`. See this part in the [old Xcode Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016994-CH4-SW6):

> - Imported C structs now have a default initializer in Swift that initializes all of the struct's fields to zero.

Since Swift 1.2 and still now, this feature is available.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and simple answer!